# Question about proof that $Ln$ is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, analytic-functions

I have a question about a step in the proof of the following theorem.

**Theorem**: $Ln: \mathbb{C}- \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \leq 0\} \to \mathbb{C}: z = re^{i \phi} \mapsto \ln r + i \phi$ $(\phi \in (-\pi, \pi), r > 0)$ is analytic.

**Proof**: We have

$$\begin{cases} u = \ln r = 1/2\ln (x^2 + y^2) \\ v = \phi\end{cases}$$

and it follows immediately that

$$\partial{u}/\partial x = x/(x^2 + y ^2), \partial{u}/\partial x = y/(x^2 + y ^2)$$

$$\begin{cases} u = \ln r = 1/2\ln (x^2 + y^2) \\ v = \phi\end{cases}$$
We have

$$\begin{cases} x = r \cos \phi \\ y = r \sin \phi\end{cases}$$

Differentiating for $x$:

$$\begin{cases} 1 = \cos \phi \partial r / \partial x - r \sin \phi \partial \phi/ \partial x \\ 0 = \sin \phi \partial r / \partial x + r \cos \phi \partial \phi/ \partial x\end{cases}$$

and solving this:

$$\partial \phi/\partial x = - \sin \phi/r = -y/(x^2+y^2)$$

and the Cauchy-Riemann conditions are satisfied.

**Questions:**

Why can we take the derivative of both sides? Don't we use implicit differentiation there? I.e., do we have to use the theorem of the implicit functions to make this proof work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Because all these functions are differentiable.
2. Yes, we are.
3. Yes, we do.

Comment: The differentiability of $\phi$ follows from the implicit function theorem?

Comment: @Math_QED Yes. Or you can use any of these facts:$$\phi(x,y)=\arccos\left(\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\text{ and }\phi(x,y)=\arcsin\left(\frac y{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you. Your comment was most helpful.